# Paged UIScrollView constantly calling scrollViewDidScroll with weird offsets

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, uiscrollview

I have some old gallery code that uses UIScrollView in a paged mode. We are trying to port the code to iOS7 but when we are getting strange behavior. In iOS7 we are constantly getting scrollViewDidScroll with weird offset of negative or some large offset that has huge exponents. Is there a known change in paged scrollviews in iOS7? Code is simple.  The image content size is hard coded at 20 pages. The reality is its dynamic based on images coming and going.

```
if (_imageScroller == nil) {
    CGRect scollViewRect = self.bounds;
    scollViewRect.size.width += IMAGE_PADDING;

    _imageScroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scollViewRect];
    CGSize contentSize = _imageScroller.bounds.size;
    contentSize.width *= 20;
    _imageScroller.contentSize = contentSize;
    _imageScroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
    _imageScroller.delegate = self;
    _imageScroller.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _imageScroller.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    _imageScroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    _imageScroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [self addSubview:_imageScroller];
}
```

Comment: What's in the `scrollViewDidScroll` method?  If the method is causing the view to scroll... it'll keep calling itself.

Comment: Right now nothing. If I set pagingEnabled to NO then it doesn't happen.

Comment: If there's nothing in `scrollViewDidScroll`, how do you know its constantly being called?

Comment: I have it overridden.. I have a break point on the closing bracket. If i put in an NSLog and log out the content offset i see it constantly updating.